# Python Error in print command. Syntax Error

Tags: python

I wrote the following code

```
from sklearn import tree

features = [[140,0],[130,1],[150,0],[170,0]]
labels = [0,0,1,1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features,labels)
result = clf.predict([[160,0]])
print (result)
```

This code is fine but my debugger is regularly showing error on print command. `print (result)` ... Have not any reason why. Debugger says

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: File "/Users/umair/Documents/Untitled.py", line 8
    print clf.predict([[160,0]])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably comes from the fact that you are using Python 3.x and not Python 2.x. Printing via `result` should produce no error. What you need is to embrace `clf.predict([[160,0]])` with parentheses, i.e. `print (clf.predict([[160,0]]))`.

In Python 2.x

```
print clf.predict([[160,0]]) # print what you expect
```

In Python 3.x

```
print clf.predict([[160,0]]) # raise a SyntaxError
print (clf.predict([[160,0]])) # print what you expect
```